# What loss function should I use to model a multimodal distribution?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, loss-functions

Hi I'm trying to use a neural network to solve a regression problem where my response variable has the following distribution

[image]

From what I understand using MSE will result in my model learning the mean of this distribution and will miss both peaks. Is there a loss function that will allow the model to learn both peaks?

Comment: The model will approximate a *conditional* mean. And the conditional distributions might not have hhese peaks, especially if whatever is giving rise to the peaks is something your set of predictors contains information about. This marginal density plot doesn't mean modelling the mean is a bad idea.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that your response variable has that distribution. What is more important is what the distribution, conditional on the predictors, is (in other words the distribution of the errors). If you think the errors are distributed normally you should use MSE, if you think they are distributed via a Laplace distribution (i.e. fat tails) you should use L1 loss.